# Looking for windows macro type software

Tags: windows

Im looking for something that will allow me to perform simple batch-type automation in the Win XP operating system.

I need to, for example, pre-pend the name of every folder a file is nested in to it's filename.

So, before: blah\yep\dave\robert.txt
after: blah\yep\dave\blah_yep_dave_robert.txt

I would also like to change all the files to read-only mode.

I used to have a tool that did this but I forgot its name.

Comment: You should learn how to accept answers. In addition, this question isn't related to programming, is it?

Comment: You are looking for AutoIT, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set PathSegmentToIgnore=%~dp0
for /r %%F in (*) do (
  if not exist %%F\NUL if not "%%~F"=="%~dpnx0" (
    rem ignore folders
    set "FilePath=%%~dpF"
    set "FilePath=!FilePath:%PathSegmentToIgnore%=!"
    set "FilePath=!FilePath!%%~nxF"
    set "FilePath=!FilePath:\=_!"
    echo Renaming "%%~nxF" to "!FilePath!"
    move "%%~F" "%%~dpF!FilePath!" >nul 2>&1
  )
)
```

Comment: what would execute a script like this?

Comment: The Windows Command Processor, `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Use VBScript or Powershell. Both are good options for scripting.